# Queue is created but never executed

Tags: mongodb, queue, lumen

I'm trying to trigger push notifications and emails in the background of my Lumen API. I created the WarningUser class that creates both queues:

```
<?php

namespace App\Utils;

use App\Jobs\ProcessNotification;
use App\Mail\AllMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class WarningUser
{

  public static function send($user, $message, $url, $data = [])
  {
    $url = env('APP_URL_FRONT') . $url;
    dispatch(new ProcessNotification($user, $data, $message, $url));

    $emailData = EmailTexts::texts('pt', $data)[$message];
    Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new AllMail($emailData['title'], $emailData['content']));

    return true;
  }
}
```

First we have the ProcessNotification job, which connects to Firebase and sends the notification:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\Notification;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;

class ProcessNotification extends Job
{
    protected $user = null;
    protected $data = null;
    protected $message = null;
    protected $url = null;

    public function __construct($user, $data, $message, $url)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        if (\is_string($this->user->token) and $this->user->token !== '') {
            $messaging = (new Factory())
                ->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/../../private-key.json')
                ->createMessaging();

            $notificationData = NotificationTexts::texts('pt', $this->data)[$this->message];
            $messageAlert = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $this->user->token)
                ->withNotification(Notification::create($notificationData['title'], $notificationData['content']))
            ->withData([ 'url' => $this->url ]);

            $messaging->send($messageAlert);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally AllMail that sends a simple email:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class AllMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $title;
    protected $body;

    public function __construct($title, $body)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    public function build()
    {

        return $this
            ->subject($this->title)
            ->view('email')
        ->with([
            'title' => $this->title,
            'body' => $this->body
        ]);
    }
}
```

I've tested both codes without using queues, and they work, but when I put the queue it stops working. The processes are recorded in my database (mongodb):

[image]

But the queue is never processed, I tried to execute `php artisan queue: work` and`php artisan queue: listen`, but neither case works.

The queue is never attempted to be processed, nor does it go to the `failed_jobs` table

My `config / queue.php` is as follows. And my .env is with `QUEUE_CONNECTION = database`

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database'),
    'connections' => [
        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

        'beanstalkd' => [
            'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => 0,
        ],

        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'your-queue-name'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],

    ],
    'failed' => [
        'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database'),
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mongodb'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],
];
```

Can someone help me? I no longer know what the error may be.

PS: At no time is a browser or console error displayed

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve, for Mongo we need to use some more settings:

The connection in queue.php must be:

```
'connections' => [
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'table'  => 'jobs',
        'queue'  => 'default',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
...
```

And we need to register the package provider that works with mongo:

`Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbQueueServiceProvider::class,`